# How to reset User control's controls to its initial state in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

In my application, i have a user control,when i am clicking on the add button of my application.it should create a object to the user control,and the created user control copy should be added to a panel control.i did all this...but what my problem is along with add button.i have a reset button.when i am clicking on this button it should reset all the user control that are added to the panel,How can i do this.
any one have an idea.please help me

And my reset code is

```
foreach (Control x in bodyPanel.Controls)
{
    if (x is TimerUserControl)
    {
       obj_TimerUserControl.ResetControl();
    }
}
```

when i execute this the last created object only get reset.remaining all are running as usual.in this code snippet Resetcontrol() is a method which was declared in TimerUserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the below code under reset button handler, it will fix the issue

```
foreach (Control ctrl in bodyPanel.Controls)
{
    if (ctrl.GetType().Name == "TimerUserControl")
    {
        TimerUserControl obj = ctrl as TimerUserControl;
        obj.ResetControl();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest way to accomplish your goal would be to create an interface with "ResetControl" as a method. Have all your various controls implement this interface and instead of checking if the control is of type "TimerUserControl" you'd check if the type is your interface.

```
 public interface IResetable
 {
      void ResetControl();
 }
```

.....

```
 foreach(var control in bodyPanel.Controls)
 {
      var resetable = control as IResetable;

      if (resetable != null)
           resetable.ResetControl();
 }
```

Comment: hi brian sorry,i didn't understand this.can you please elaborate.

Comment: You have a class called "TimerUserControl" which would is declared with something like "public class TimerUserControl : UserControl". Create an interface like I suggested above then change your usercontrol declaration to be "public class TimerUserControl : UserControl, IResetable". Do the same for any other "type" that you need to reset.

Comment: hi Brain,i did it.but i get an error.when i declare, var resetable =control as IResetable;an error like the type or Namespace name "IResetable" could not be found.

Comment: You need to create the interface also like the example I provided.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not so clear..But i try to describe what i understood..As I understand, There can be 2 probability..

PROBABILITY - 1 : You have a class that you called as "User Control" and when this class instantiated (created a new instance of this object -In Net framework all are objects-) and that instantiated object initializes/implements itself to a parent object..

After added to parent when user/developer need, the instantiated object can set to default of its initial values with some filter options (i.e. by index no )

PROBABILITY-2 : The parent object remove all added elements

these two probability can solve with same way..

here some sample code :

```
//This is sample parent object

public class Container : Panel
{

  // In your situation this list is your controls
  public List<NumBox> Elements { get; set; }

  public Container()
  {
  }
  public Container( List<NumBox> numericBoxList )
  {
    this.Elements.AddRange( numericBoxList ) ;
  }

  public void Add ( NumBox numericBoxInstance )
  {

    // we check that elements has our numbox instance or not..
    // if our instance is not in the elements then find method returns null
    if (this.Elements.Find( numericBoxInstance ) == null)
    {
      this.Elements.Add ( numericBoxInstance )
    }

    public void DeleteElement ( NumBox numboxInstance )
    {
      this.Elements.Remove (numboxInstance );
    }

    public void DeleteAllElements ()
    {
      this.Elements = null;
      // The IENumerable objects such as Lists can be easily set the object to the 
      // "initialization moment" - something like just create a new and empty object - 
      // with assigning to "null"..CSharp compiler as clever as understand that you want clear all
    }

    public void UpdateElement (int indexNo, NumBox updatedNumBox)
    {
      this.Elements[indexNo] = updatedNumBox;
    }

// And The Sample Child object

public class NumBox : TextBox
{

   public NumBox()
   {
   }

   public NumBox ( int value )
   {
     this.Text = value.ToString();
   }

   //overloads for other numeric options such as short, long, decimal, float etc.

    public void Reset()
    {
      this.Text = null;
    }
   // Some Other Useful Methods that you need in the project
}
```

And sample usage :

```
    int i = 12345;
    var box = new NumBox (i);

    var parent = new Container();
    parent.Add( box );

    var j = parent.Elements.FindIndex ( box ); 
    // FindIndex is a built-in IENumerable method like Find() or others that you can see in Intellisense

    if (j > = 0)
    {
      parent.Elements[j].Reset();
    }
    var box1 = new NumBox(987654);

    parent.UpdateElement(j, box1);
    parent.DeleteAllElements();
```

Hope this sample enlighten your way..

Comment: Thank You sihirbazzz for your valuable suggestion

Comment: @naredlanitheshreddy We all are here to learn and help eachother..You are welcome and Thank you to your kind, gentle Thanks ;) BTW, please sign as answered if one of answers are useful for you